spaCy Custom NER model only works on its own
I have created a custom NER model for spaCy and can load and run it and it works as expected.

nlp = spacy.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/Custom_NER/trained_models/output/model-best')

text = "I want to book a ticket for 2 adults and 2 children travelling to Norwich from London Liverpool Street departing at 09:00 and arriving by 14:00 leaving Tomorrow and returning on 14/05/24"

doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
  print(ent.text, "  ->>>>  ", ent.label_)

Outputs:
```2   ->>>>   STATION
to   ->>>>   TO
Norwich   ->>>>   STATION
from   ->>>>   FROM
London   ->>>>   STATION
Liverpool   ->>>>   STATION
Street   ->>>>   STATION
departing at   ->>>>   TIME_KEY
09:00   ->>>>   TICKET_TIME
arriving by   ->>>>   TIME_KEY
14:00   ->>>>   TICKET_TIME
leaving Tomorrow   ->>>>   TIME_KEY
returning   ->>>>   TO
14/05/24   ->>>>   DATE```

However, if I try to combine my NER model with a built-in pipeline so I can use other features using

    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', exclude=["ner"])
    
    ner_nlp = spacy.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/Custom_NER/trained_models/output/model-best')
    nlp.add_pipe("ner", source=ner_nlp)


My output is suddenly:
I want   ->>>>   STATION
to book   ->>>>   STATION
a ticket   ->>>>   STATION
for 2   ->>>>   STATION
adults and   ->>>>   STATION
2 children   ->>>>   STATION
travelling to   ->>>>   STATION
Norwich from   ->>>>   STATION
London Liverpool   ->>>>   STATION
Street departing   ->>>>   STATION
at 09:00   ->>>>   STATION
and arriving   ->>>>   STATION
by 14:00   ->>>>   STATION
leaving Tomorrow   ->>>>   STATION
and returning   ->>>>   STATION
on 14/05/24   ->>>>   STATION

So I am unsure why this would be happening.
I believe it maybe something to do with the new model using a transformer and the built in model using words2vec
Any help would be gladly appreciated
